# how can i let return properly work? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, return

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
 async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.topic == None:
            pass
        else:
            if "[SSbot deactivation]" in message.channel.topic:
                print(message.channel.name)
                return
            else:
                pass
```

even though i've got `return`, still running. can anyone help?.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "still running"? What should happen because of reaching the `return`, and what happens instead? `return` only means that this call to `on_message` will end (and it only ends when the results is checked, asynchronously). It does not prevent future calls to `on_message`, just like with any ordinary function. Please read [ask]. "can anyone help?" is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: just fixed it and thanks for your advice, still not used to this, next time i'll ask a way better formed question!

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement only stops the current function - if the function is called again, it will still run. The `on_message` function is called every time a message is sent, so that return statement will not stop the bot. If you are trying to end the python script, you could use the `exit()` command (note that python IDLE shows a prompt to confirm).